# OCR and Raspberry Pi 3 model B + Camera module v2 Questions

Tags: pi-3

Sorry for the question, i had no idea how to properly ask, but i got a problem.
I need to Create a script, that identifies 8 Digits on a display, automaticly implies it into a VPN and confirms it.
On my first step i want a OCR to properly work, i tried out guides but most of the time they caused problems, and i coudlnt keep going after certain steps.
If anyone here could help me, or send me a good / easy guide for beginners would be nice.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense... mostly because the terms you use are nonsensical, or have no meaning in the current context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrt the OCR part, [`Tesseract`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract_(software)) may be what you need. It's available in a [Python wrapper](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/), and should run on RPi.

Not sure what you mean by `... implies it into a VPN and confirms it.` , but get the OCR working, and re-post this part of the question when you've a clearer idea of where you're going.

Comment: Basicly, You they log into a network with a Username + Password + a Token which is displayed on a monitor, that changes every 30 seconds. They want to have the whole process Automized, including the 30 seconds token being copied into the Login "page".

Comment: Ah - ok then. So you're doing OCR on an image to get the value for a token which is in turn used for authentication. Does `Tesseract` hold any interest for you as an approach to doing the OCR?

Comment: Yes,  i have to do this for a worker experience, even tho they dont really help me   lol.
I do not have any experience wit hthis yet , so im kinda just googlin etc.
They told me not to use tesseract, but use  
https://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~auerswal/ssocr/ .
its still pretty hard for me to understand, i dont have any experience with python etc aswell so ye^^.

Comment: "They" have a reason for selecting `ssocr` I assume, but I can't even guess what that might be. Anyway - you can run `ssocr` from a Python program using the `subprocess` module - you can Google `Python subprocess` and get lots of information, or [start here](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/os/subprocess-for-system-administrators).

Comment: im currently stuck on installing imlib2 , whic his needed for ssocr.
Im trying to use make on the Makefile, but it says it doesnt find it.
The Readme told me to do so, 

also "make install" doesnt work, because appearently theres no  rules to create "install"

Comment: Are you doing this on the Raspberry Pi? If so, I don't think you need to compile it, but here's an easy way to check: from your command line, enter this: `apt-cache search imlib2`. If you get a match (and you will, 'cause I just checked), you can install the imlib2 binary (already compiled) package as follows: 1. `sudo apt-get update` 2. `sudo apt-get upgrade` 3. `sudo apt-get install imlib2`

Comment: Yeah, i just realized its that easy^^ i've downloaded all parts for it including imlib2 now.

Comment: Alright, the OCR is working for me , thx for ur help